# how to put checkbox in xml file that will produce a PDF

Tags: xml, xslt, input, checkbox

I have an xml File that generates a PDF. I need to put checkboxes in there but I can't get the right syntax.
Here is the code:

```
<fo:block font-weight="normal">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="question23[2]/checked = 'true'">Yes</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

Here is what I am hoping for:

```
<fo:block font-weight="normal">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="question23[2]/checked = 'true'"><input type="checkbox"/>Yes</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

Just putting `<input type="checkbox"/>`, doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the XSL-FO standard covers form controls so you might need to check whether you use or can use a FOP processor that supports them as an extension, like https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.form-field.

Comment: I think you should also be more specific. Do you what a visual checked box character? Or do you actually want a form field? If you want a form field then wouldn't you place the field and set it checked or not?